# Is it possible to simplify getting a tuple value with an if statement, inside of a for statement?

Tags: python

For example, can I simplify this code using something like enumerate?

```
list1 = ('c_test1', 'c_test2', 'test3', 'c_test4', 'test5', 'test6', 'c_test7') 
tuple1 = ['list1', 'list2', 'list3', 'list4'] 

i = 0
for x in list(list1): 
    if "c" in str(x):
       print(tuple1[i])
       i+=1
```

Comment: You'll want to use a list comprehension.

Comment: Also, your list is the tuple and your tuple is the list.

Comment: `zip(list(filter(lambda x: 'c' in x, list1)), tuple1)` gives you `[('c_test1', 'list1'), ('c_test2', 'list2'), ('c_test4', 'list3'), ('c_test7', 'list4')]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter and list comprehension combination.

```
list1 = ('c_test1', 'c_test2', 'test3', 'c_test4', 
          'test5', 'test6', 'c_test7')
tuple1 = ['list1', 'list2', 'list3', 'list4']

print [tuple1[i] for i,v in enumerate(filter(lambda x: "c" in str(x), list1))]
```

**output**

['list1', 'list2', 'list3', 'list4']